# post request in nodejs with basic authentication

Tags: node.js, express, orientdb

I have a db server with predefined http request(using orientdb)

I want write a post request in the following shape and form

```
http://localhost:2480/database/demo/plocal
```

The database name (demo) will come from a form in html and I have to use basic authentication in my request in order to authenticate and create the database.

I am using node.js and express to create this api, what should be the code form my post request to contain all this information.

so far I have created the following routes but I am lost on how do I create this post request:

```
// Create DB
app.get('/createdb', (req, res) => {
    res.render('createdb');
});

app.post('/createdb', (req, res) => {


    // http://localhost:2480/database/demo/plocal
    const serverString = 'http://localhost:2480/database/';
    const dbName = req.body.dbname;
    const dbType = '/plocal';

    console.log(serverString + dbName + dbType);
    res.send('createdb page');
});
```

in my console.log I can see the db name from my form.
Thanks in advance

Comment: app.post() is a post request. For route settings refer to https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

To make API calls use PostMan.

For authentication, you can use token or session. Personally I use npm express-session

Session set up in app.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: '2C44-1T58-WFpQ350',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 3600000 * 2
  }
}));
```

Login method

```
router.post('/login', async function (req, res, next) {

  //Run DB query check
  try {
  //Call db check if user is in user Table if yes set session
    var result = await qp.executeAndFetchPromise('select * from user where email = ? AND ava_status = 1', [req.body.email], dbconfig);
    if (result.length == 1) {
      //encryption to be added later
      if (result[0].password == req.body.password) {
        //set session
        req.session.userid = result[0].id;
        req.session.name = result[0].name;
        req.session.role = result[0].role;
        req.session.group_id = result[0].group_id;
        req.session.userinfo = result[0];

        // res.render('index' , user = result[0])
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
      }

    } else {
      throw (new Error());
    }
  }
  catch (error) {

    res.render('login', feedback = { "message": "Invalid username/password" });
  }


});
```

in App,js

```
var debugging = false; //IMPORTANT
var API = false;
function authChecker(req, res, next) {
  if (API == false) {
    let userRoles = custom.getAllRoles();
    let temp = arrayFindIndex(userRoles, x => x == req.session.role );
    if (temp != -1 ) {
      next();
    } else {
      if (debugging) {
        if (!req.session.role && !req.session.role) {
          req.session.role = 'ADMIN';
          req.session.userid = 1;
          req.session.name = "Marcia test Debugging"
        }

        next();
      } else {
        // var err = new Error('Session timeout, Please login again');
        // err.status = 502;
        // next(err);
        res.redirect('/login');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Run authCehcker method on routes require authentication

```
    //Setting web routes
app.use('/', indexRouter); // public can access

//Routes under will be checked
app.use(authChecker); //routes under this method will be checked by the authChecker method
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
app.use('/brand', brand);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl: `curl -X POST -h 'authorization: <basic auth here>' http://localhost:2480/database/demo/plocal`